# Moving camera to show direction of movement aligned with the top

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android application using google maps, the app will be mainly used when the user is moving.. I would like to know if it is possible that the camera move so that direction of movement will be aligned with the top just like this picture

[image]

note that i'm not using Navigation..